# How can I Json (or Gson) a class like "objects to string" and after "string to objects"

Tags: android, json, class, gson

My question is about an error occurred when I use my followed class:

```
public class ClassePai {

    private int ID;
    private String Nome;
    private ArrayList<ClasseFilho> listaParentes;

    public ClassePai( int id, String nome){

        this.ID = id;
        this.Nome = nome;       

        listaParentes = new ArrayList<ClasseFilho>();

    }

    public void addParente(ClasseFilho classeFilho) {

        listaParentes.add(classeFilho);

    }

    public ClasseFilho getParente( int index ){

        return listaParentes.get(index);

    }

    public int length(){

        return listaParentes.size();
    }

    public String Nome(){

        return this.Nome;
    }

    public int ID(){
        return this.ID;
    }

}
```

and this "son" class:

```
public class ClasseFilho {

    private String Nome;
    private String Grau;

    public ClasseFilho( String nome, String grau ){

        this.Nome = nome;
        this.Grau = grau;

    }

    public String Nome(){

        return this.Nome;
    }

    public String Grau(){
        return this.Grau;
    }

}
```

This is my Activity:

```
public class TesteClasseActivity extends Activity {

    private ClassePai cp;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        cp = new ClassePai( 1, "Junior" );

        cp.addParente( new ClasseFilho( "Vinicius", "filho" ) );
        cp.addParente( new ClasseFilho( "Luciene", "namorada" ) );

        //old call returning error
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), cp.length(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf( cp.length() ), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        cp.addParente( new ClasseFilho( "Veraldo", "pai" ) );
        cp.addParente( new ClasseFilho( "Sônia", "mãe" ) );

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf( cp.length() ), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        ( (TextView) findViewById(R.id.edit) ).setText( cp.Nome() );

        Button bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        bt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), cp.getParente(1).Nome(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
          });

            //my try of doing this, but don't work             

            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();

            obj.put("teste", cp);

            // BUT unfortunatelly
            // 
            // obj.toString() returns this:
            //
            // {"teste":"my.package.name.ClassePai@40516650"}
            // 
            // BUT...


            //wondering on net, I've deceided to try Gson:

            //first part: object to string

            Gson obj = new Gson();

            obj.toJson(cp);

            String obj_in_xml = obj.toString();

            Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext() , obj_in_xml, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            //no error, appear works fine, but...


            //second part: string to object

            Gson obj2 = new Gson();

            ClassePai new_cp = obj2.fromJson( obj_in_xml, ClassePai.class);

            Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext() , new_cp.Nome(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            //give me an error com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException
            //and I could't find my properties in obj.toString(), but only codes like:
            //
            //adapter=com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$7@40529278]
            //
            // and don't find any of the object's string properties in the obj.toString() string
            //
            // what I'm doing wrong????


    }
}
```

How can I do to save this object with children in a text format, and after load from String to the objects again?

Please help me!!!

Comment: Post your stacktrace.  Or even better: read it yourself.  Your question is answered there in clear text with 90% probability

Comment: Yeah, please paste the logcat message, and point to the line that is throwing the exception.

Comment: 04-03 14:45:36.543: E/AndroidRuntime(262): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-03 14:45:36.543: E/AndroidRuntime(262): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{br.junior.testeclasse/br.junior.testeclasse.TesteClasseActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0xa
04-03 14:45:36.543: E/AndroidRuntime(262):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)

This you want?

Comment: Possibly.   Just edit your question and post logcat snippet as code

Answer (score 0):

May be the problem is here:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), cp.length(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Here the second parametr must be an integer reference to a string resource or string value. If you want to show the size as a toast message use this variant:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(cp.length()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

**Update**

To convert JSON Object to String use:

```
String myString = myJSONObject.toString();
```

String to JSONObject:

```
JSONObject myJSONObject = getJSONObject(myString);
```

Comment: This works fine... why Toast don't warning this? There isn't cast check in Java? Thanks man... But what about the main question, how to transport objects to string and vice-versa with JSon?

Comment: thanks @Bakyt, but that does not work for me. please see my updated question

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is that, you can't pass a int type to the method "Toast.makeText". You can convert the int to the String and show it. By String lengthString = String.valueOf(cp.length()).

The second problem you can use the xml to save and read string.

```
    JSONObject person = new JSONObject();
    String spmnoName = "spmno";
    try{
        person.put("name", spmnoName);
        String getString = person.getString("name");
    }catch(JSONException ex){
        throw new RuntimeException(ex); 
    }
```

Comment: Ok, cast problem solved... but what about the main question, how to transport objects to string and vice-versa with JSon?

Comment: I don't know that why you insist on use the json to save the string. Json is a key/value pairs. You may use json like this.